# Efficient way to calculate distance to the edge of a subset of the plane (integer coordinates only)

Tags: algorithm, distance, plane

I am working on a program to generate an elevation map (for fun). The slowest part right now is an algorithm I wrote to get the distance to the "edge of the region". Here are some images showing what I mean:

[image]

The points which border points outside the region should have distance 0. Other than that, I do not care much what the distance function is. My algorithm results in something like an L1 distance, but something else would be fine, too, if there are existing ways to do this.

My existing code's procedure: Check each point in the set to see if it is on the edge (it borders something not in the set). Label all of these with 0. Remove them and call the function recursively on the remaining points, and add 1 to all of their results. Here is the code:

```
def get_distances_from_edge(self, point_set):
    if len(point_set) == 0:
        return {}
    res = {}
    points_on_edge = [p for p in point_set if any(n not in point_set for n in self.get_neighbors(*p))]  # flagged as slow: genexpr
    assert len(points_on_edge) > 0, "point set has no edge members:\n{}".format(sorted(point_set))
    for p in points_on_edge:
        res[p] = 0
    interior_point_set = point_set - set(points_on_edge)
    if len(interior_point_set) > 0:
        interior_distances = self.get_distances_from_edge(interior_point_set)
        for p, d in interior_distances.items():
            res[p] = d + 1
    return res
```

This achieves the desired result but very slowly for large regions (I am doing it thousands of times, and each region is thousands or tens of thousands of pixels).

Is there a better way to do this? I thought about possibly getting linear time (in the number of pixels in the set) by starting an "ant" at the first point in the first row, and having it walk around the edge with the wall always on its left, and those are the edge points, instead of checking every point in the set every time. However, this will miss interior holes and disconnected components (which can happen). I want to make no assumptions about the shape of the set.

Comment: @beaker Thanks, I was not familiar with the term "distance transform". Googling that and fast marching turned up some stuff that I'll try.